# How to Export Data from SQL server Compact To Access MDB

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, export, sql-server-ce

I need a solution to transfer all data from SQL Server CE to Access mdb database.

I tried this approach http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/483989/HowplustoplusExportplusSQLplusTablesplusToplusAcce#answer2 (solution # 2) but getting an error "No database specified in connection string or IN clause."

The code works if I connect to non-compact SQL server.

I guess the problem is with connection string in IN clause but I cannot figure out how to change it.

Here is my code:

```
private void ExportTable(string tableName, string source, string destination)
{
    var connStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}", destination);
    var cmdText = string.Format("SELECT * INTO {0} FROM [{0}] IN ''[Data Source={1};Max Database Size='4000';Persist Security Info=False;];", tableName, source);

    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // error on this line
            }

            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The connection string: Data Source={1};Max Database Size='4000';Persist Security Info=False; working ok when I connect to the database directly.

**UPDATE:** Apparently the format of the source DB in IN Clause should be as following:
 [*type*; DATABASE = *path*]

(see: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-2010-runtime-error-3170-could-not-find/0b085797-618a-488f-b1b4-30af00f04b3f)

When I use

```
var cmdText = string.Format("SELECT * INTO {0} FROM [{0}] IN ''[SqlServer CE; DATABASE={1}];", tableName, source);
```

I am getting different error: Could not find installable ISAM.

Do you know correct *type* for SQLServer CE? Is it supported at all? I could not find any info about it.

I have also tried: SQL CE, SQLSERVER.CE, Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5, Microsoft.SQLSERVER.MOBILE.OLEDB.3.0 etc. - Same error...

Comment: Can you show whats inside the string "source"?

Comment: @Tom Studee: both source and destinations hold path to sdf and mdb files respectively.

Comment: maybe here is described type -  http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce#microsoft-sqlserver-ce-oledb-3-5  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the stumbling block here is that the trick you are trying to use requires an ODBC connection to the SQL Server and as far as I know there is no ODBC driver for SQL Server Compact. I'm pretty sure that the syntax `[ODBC;Driver=...]` in Access has no OLEDB equivalent, so the trick won't work with SQL Server Compact. (As you discovered, it *does* work with "real" SQL Server because ODBC connections are supported for that platform.)

I was curious to see what I could accomplish in C# using an OLEDB connection to the SQL Server Compact database (which is [supported](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce#microsoft-sqlserver-ce-oledb-3-5), as @MrZak pointed out in his comment). I came up with the following. It pulls the SQL table into a DataTable, sets the status of each row to "Added", and then updates (inserts into) the corresponding table in Access.

```csharp
string myConnectionStringMDB =
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data Source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\fromCE.mdb;";
string myConnectionStringSQL =
        "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;" +
        @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\test\myData.sdf;";

using (OleDbConnection conSQL = new OleDbConnection(),
        conMDB = new OleDbConnection())
{
    conSQL.ConnectionString = myConnectionStringSQL;
    conSQL.Open();
    conMDB.ConnectionString = myConnectionStringMDB;
    conMDB.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(),
            cmdMDB = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmdSQL.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL;
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Table1]";

        var daSQL = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
        var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        daSQL.Fill(dt);

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            // change row status from "Unchanged" to "Added" so .Update below will insert them
            dr.SetAdded();
        }

        cmdMDB.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmdMDB.Connection = conMDB;
        cmdMDB.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Table1]";
        var daMDB = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdMDB);
        var cbuilderMDB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(daMDB);
        cbuilderMDB.QuotePrefix = "[";
        cbuilderMDB.QuoteSuffix = "]";
        daMDB.Update(dt);
    }
    conSQL.Close();
    conMDB.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm still new to this, but "private void" from what I understand cant be imported or exported. Its only readable in that class or as a executable.

Comment: Sorry, but you better read the question. private void it is signature of my C# method - it has nothing to do with the data export.