# Moving Data from DataSet to Oracle Database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2008, ms-access, dataset

I've been squeezing my mind trying to figure out why my code isn't working.
I am trying to read from a DataSet that filled with data from access database  and insert the data into an Oracle database which is created previously.
When I try the following code it won't work and although I use the try and catch block, when debugging it would freeze and won't show me any error. 
if can see that I have commented out the block just right above my foreach loop..which works perfectly, Any help from you is so much appreciated :

```
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query1 = "Select * from Test;";
        string StrQuery= "Insert Into TEST (ID, DATA) Values (:ID, :DATA)";

        Conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        Conn.Open();
        using (OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query1, connection1))
            {
                DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                adapter1.Fill(ds1);
               // no need for refilling DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]

               // insterting the dataset into oracle
                try
                {
                    using (OracleConnection connect = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
                    {
                        connect.Open();
                        using (OracleCommand comma = new OracleCommand(StrQuery, connect))
                        {


                                /*comma.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":ID", 2));
                                comma.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":DATA", 2));
                                comma.ExecuteNonQuery();*/
                            foreach (DataRow drRow in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    comma.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":ID", drRow[i]));
                                    comma.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":DATA", drRow[i]));
                                    comma.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }


                            connect.Close();
                            connect.Dispose();
                        }
                    }

                }

                catch (OracleException)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }

        Conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping columns but adding the drRow[i] as values in the parameters.
I do not think this is what you intended.

skip the columns loop and add the first column value to id and second column value to data.
that should be what you wanted.... if not then describe a bit more...

Comment: Hello Judgemaik, Thanks for replying. I have noticed the loop and made some changes but still not quite sure what you mean by adding values in the parameters. Is there another way that I can use to directly move data from datagridview to my oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Judgemaik's answer, I believe you need to do something like this instead (can't really tell what the names of the columns in your access table are but you get the idea:

```
foreach (DataRow drRow in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    comma.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":ID", drRow["IDColumnFromAccessDB"]));
    comma.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":DATA", drRow["DATAColumnFromAccessDB"]));
    comma.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach is outlined in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17255343/2144390). In that particular case I was moving data from SQL Server Compact into Access, but the same idea could very well be used to move data between any two OleDb data sources.

It uses an `OleDbDataAdapter` to pull the source table into a `DataTable`, copies it over to another `DataTable`, and then uses another `OleDbDataAdapter` to update the corresponding table in the destination database.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect, Thanks :-)