# Migrate Microsoft Access Database to SQL Server Compact Edtion 4.0

Tags: database, ms-access, migration, sql-server-ce, database-migration

I have created an application that uses a Microsoft Access database, which I am having some issues with and so want to migrate to Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition.

I have looked into several tools but I can't find anything currently around that would convert the Access database to SQL CE. Does anyone have any advice for re-creating the tables quickly or links to software tools that I could use? Ideally a free solution, or pretty cheap (>£50?)

I have tried:

- Microsoft SSMA - This tool supports every version of SQL server except the compact edition.
- Primeworks - The link to download the tool is now dead

Comment: I'm curious what issues you are having that moving your db to SQL will solve?  While SQL does offer more advantages, if your application doesn't work with a local db, unless it's a size issue, chance are you'll have the some problems with the db in SQL

Comment: @Gene it solves lots of issues when it is multi-user.  I use SQL Server Express Edition which is free and I converted to it about 4 or 5 years ago in an application for a small business.  It made fantastic difference to those who had to access the database from remote offices. I'm just trying to remember how I did it, so I can answer the question

Comment: You might be interested in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17255343/2144390). It copies data from SQL_CE to Access, but the approach should also work in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Gene it's to do with reliability over a network with multiple users. Amongst other things, a memo field is getting corrupted randomly every couple of weeks, and the database gets a strange error that is only repairable through a compact and repair of the database...there's other issues with data loss too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Use [SSMA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43690) to migrate from Access to a free SQL Server edition (LocalDB / Express)

2: In Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (also free), use my free "[SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/)" to migrate from the SQL Server database to SQL Compact (either via "one-click" or via scripts)

Comment: perfect! nice tool btw, edited your post and added links

Comment: keep in mind that there is no ODBC driver for the compact edition. Thus while in typical Access migrations to SQL server you can then continue to use the Access as the user interface to SQL server. With the compact edition you cannot use Access for reporting etc. So compact edition of SQL server does not have ODBC drivers like the free edition of SQL express edition.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment above, I had to remember how I did this before.

I used (and still do) SQL Server Express Edition which is a free download.  I am not sure the difference between that and the Compact Edition you refer to.  Nor am I sure of what your constraints are so this might not work for you but...

Step 1) Install SQL Server Express and SQL Server Management Studio.  The come in a single package.  I think you have to get yourself a Microsoft Account to download it

Step 2) Create a New Database to import your access Database into

Step 3) In this new database choose tasks/import data

Step 4) Select Access as the source (choose the file), destination SQL Server Native Client (and select the database you are in)

Step 5) Tidy up.  I had to create and run some scripts to copy table, set Autonum primary keys to the correct value and such.  In the end I created a couple of stored procedures to help me.

Here.s one.  I can't remember the detail, so take it as you wish

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Alan Chandler
-- Create date: 10th May 2011
-- Description: Migrates a single table (passed as a parameter) to database
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MigrateTable] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @table_name sysname
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @table_name = RTRIM(@table_name)
    DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @column_name AS NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @object_id AS int
    DECLARE @has_identity AS int
    DECLARE @comma_needed AS bit
    DECLARE column_list_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name ;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    -- Do Complete Process as a transaction in case it goes wrong
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT @object_id = OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@Table_name))
    SELECT @has_identity = ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTY(@object_id,'TableHasIdentity'),0)
    SET @cmd = N'DELETE FROM '+QUOTENAME(@table_name)
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
    SET @cmd = N'';
    IF @has_identity > 0 
    BEGIN
        -- If We Have an Identity Column we need to allow the insertion without thinking about it
        SET @cmd = N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+N' ON;'
    END
    -- Create an Insert Statement ...
    SET @cmd = @cmd+N'INSERT INTO [dbo].'+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+N' (';
    -- ... Listing all the column names
    OPEN column_list_cursor;
    SET @comma_needed = N'FALSE'
    FETCH NEXT FROM column_list_cursor INTO @Column_name
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @comma_needed = N'TRUE' SET @cmd = @cmd + N',';
        SET @cmd = @cmd + QUOTENAME(@Column_name)
        SET @comma_needed = N'TRUE';
        FETCH NEXT FROM column_list_cursor INTO @Column_name
    END
    SET @cmd = @cmd+N') SELECT '
    -- Now start to create the Select Statement from the other database ...
    SET @comma_needed = N'FALSE'
    CLOSE column_list_cursor;
    -- ... again listing all the column names
    OPEN column_list_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM column_list_cursor INTO @Column_name
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @comma_needed = N'TRUE' SET @cmd = @cmd + N',';
        SET @cmd = @cmd + QUOTENAME(@Column_name)
        SET @comma_needed = N'TRUE';
        FETCH NEXT FROM column_list_cursor INTO @Column_name
    END
    CLOSE column_list_cursor
    DEALLOCATE column_list_cursor
    SET @cmd = @cmd + N' FROM [Accuvision].[dbo].'+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+N';'
    IF @has_identity > 0 
    BEGIN
        -- Switch identity function back on and reseed the value
        SET @cmd = @cmd+N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+N' OFF;'
        SET @cmd = @cmd+N'DBCC CHECKIDENT ('+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+N',RESEED)'
    END
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
    COMMIT
    PRINT N'Migration of '+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+N' complete'
END
```

This was called from a second procedure.  I can't post all of it as the cleanup I did is confidential, but the generic bits follow..

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Alan Chandler
-- Create date: 10th May 2011
-- Description: Migrates Accuvision Database (itself imported
--              from an access database of the same name) into
--              the current database, avoiding IDENTITY ISSUES
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Migrate] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Table_Name nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE table_list_cursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE';
    -- Turn off contraint checking on all tables
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

    OPEN table_list_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM table_list_cursor INTO @Table_name
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @Table_Name NOT IN ( N'WebSiteLeads', N'Debug_Log', N'Config',N'People',N'UserLog',N'ProcedureType',N'DailyDates',N'Locks',N'CallLog')
            EXEC [dbo].[MigrateTable] @Table_name
        FETCH NEXT FROM table_list_cursor INTO @Table_name
    END
    CLOSE table_list_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE table_list_cursor;

--- Lots of calls to 
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [XXXX] ON;
-- do stuff to table
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [XXXX] OFF;
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('XXXX',RESEED)
--
    PRINT N'Last Step, resetting constraints'
    EXEC sp_msForEachTable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"  
    PRINT N'DATA MIGRATION COMPLETE'    
END
```

I hope that helps you.  Sorry if not, but as you can see its nearly 5 years ago I created those procedures - used them a few times until it all worked and I migrated the database and never looked at them again until just now

If you have security issues etc see
https://www.chandlerfamily.org.uk/2011/04/importing-access-database-into-sqlserver-when-the-former-is-protected-with-a-workgroup-file/

If you want some backup procedures etc I put them here
https://www.chandlerfamily.org.uk/2011/05/an-automated-backup-regime-for-a-small-sql-server-database/

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I decided to go with Erik's answer for simplicity